# Nav bar drops into two lines at different zooms

Tags: html, css, zooming, nav

I have made a nav bar that at my defult zoom likes fine, but upon zooming in OR out it drops into two lines, completly ruining it.

Any idea how to stop this from happening? 
Any help will be much appreciated,
Here is the HTML

```
<nav>
    <ul>
        <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="generalGuidance.html">General Guidance</a></li>
        <li><a href="whyGrow.html">Why grow?</a></li>
        <li><a href="usefullSites.html">Usefull Sites</a>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="http://www.bbc.co.uk/gardening/">BBC Gardening</a></li>
                <li><a href="http://www.channel4.com/4homes/rooms/outdoors/garden-grow-your-own">Channel Four Gardening</a></li>
                <li><a href ="http://ngb.org/gardening_links/index.cfm">National Garden</a></li>    
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="carrot.html#bottom">How To Grow</a> <!--Links to the bottom of the how to grow carrots page -->
            <ul>
                <li><a href="carrot.html">Carrots</a></li>
                <li><a href="turnip.html">Turnips</a></li>
                <li><a href="radish.html">Radishs</a></li>
                <li><a href="parsnip.html">Parsnips</a></li>
                <li><a href="leek.html">Leeks</a></li>
                <li><a href="onion.html">Onions</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>   
        <li><a href="Forums">Forums</a></li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

and the CSS

```
    nav{
    width:1000px;
}
nav a{
    font-weight:500;
    font-family: "arial", Times, serif; 
}

/*Hides the child elements*/
nav ul ul {
    display: none;
}
/* Displays the child elements on mouse over*/
    nav ul li:hover > ul {
        display: block;
        z-index: 20;
}

    nav ul {
    background-color: #3C7F1E; 
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 9px rgba(0,0,0,0.15);
    padding: 0 20px;
    border-radius: 10px;  /*Gives the nav bar rounded corners*/
    list-style: none;
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 0 auto;
    width:960px;
}
nav ul:after {
        content: ""; clear: both; display: block;
    }

/*Makes the nav bar hozizontal*/
    nav ul li {
    float: left; 
}
/*Changes the elements color on hover*/
    nav ul li:hover {
        background: #577F45;
    }
        nav ul li:hover a {
            color: #fff;
        }

    nav ul li a {
        display: block; padding: 25px 40px;
        color: #fff; text-decoration: none;
    }
    nav ul ul {
    background: #337F12; border-radius: 0px; padding: 0;
    position: absolute; top: 100%;
    width:auto;
}
    nav ul ul li {
        float: none; 
        border-top: 1px solid #4D7F37;
        border-bottom: 1px solid #4D7F37;
        position: relative; 
    }
        nav ul ul li a {
            padding: 15px 40px;
            color: #fff;
        }   
            nav ul ul li a:hover {
                background: #4D7F37;
            }
```

Comment: This fixed it
nav ul li {
 float: left;
 width:160px; 
}

Although it does not look as good as it did, because the text now goes into two lines.

Answer (score 0):

Try it..

```
nav {
    max-width: 100%;  /*Edit*/
    width: 1000px;
}

nav ul {
    background-color: #3C7F1E;
    border-radius: 10px;
    box-shadow: 0 0 9px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
    display: inline-block;
    list-style: none outside none;
    margin: 0 auto;
    max-width: 100%;     /*Edit*/
    padding: 0;          /*Edit*/
    position: relative;
    width: 960px;
       }
```